# How to share putty session/screen with others in same network?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, putty, vnc

I am working on a windows machine which connects to Linux server, and I feel need of sharing my Putty session (for linux server) with others in my team (remotely located). All of us are in same network.

I cannot use application like VNC,WebEx,Lync or any other screen sharing tool. Wondering if there is any utility in Putty or linux which help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Is this you too http://superuser.com/questions/1112296/how-to-stream-a-static-video-file or did you just do the bounty for that for some reason? I left a comment if it's you; otherwise, the OP hasn't been seen since 8/11 when it was asked. I left a comment regardless so I wasn't sure if the tag in it's comment with your name would notify you are not but in any case, check it out.  +1 just for the hell of it... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could try on [multiuser](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser)

> screen can allow multiple users to access the same session. This can
>   be useful for all sorts of information sharing, from helpdesk
>   applications to extreme programming. By default, multiuser mode is
>   disabled, for security reasons.

**Examples**

> Add user phil with password moo, gives him full permission to
>   everything:
>
> acladd phil QSsUHy/lmL5CM
>
> Remove all of phil's permissions (but he can still connect to the
>   session and view all windows):
>
> aclchg phil -rwx "#?"
>
> Allow phil to write to windows 1, 2, and 7. Also allow him to run the
>   commands select, next, and prev. Add a new user, bob, and give him the
>   same permissions:
>
> aclchg phil,bob +rwx 1,2,7,select,next,prev

notably nothing need to be installed on client

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible scenarios

1) You are the only person that can shh to Linux server. And your colleagues need to use your connection to reach resources on this machine and beyond it.
You can set a tunnel in Putty under Connction->SSH->tunnels section.

For example,  adding a rule with source of 2222, empty destination and Dynamic option will enable your colleagues to set IP adress of your PC as a SOCK proxy in Firefox and use your SSH tunnel for stuff

2) If you need your colleagues to watch what you are typing in console and at the same time they can establish their own sessions you'd better use screen utility on Linux server.

With

```
screen -S 12345
```

you start a screen. Then your colleagues who are sshed to the same server with

```
screen -x 12345
```

will connect to the same screen and would see what you are typing.
Here is some tutorial about screen https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen